# Store mongoose query result in a variable

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a query that is returned through a higher-order-function like this:

Query:

```
const final_ids;

        final_ids = InterviewWorflowDao.findAll({}, (err, res) => {
            const user_ids = res.map(r => r.clientId);
            return user_ids;            
        })
console.log('show data', final_ids);
```

Higher-order-function

```
const findAll = (query, cb) => {
    model.find(query, null, cb);
}
```

What I want to achieve is: get the array of ids returned by query into a variable `final_ids;` But  `console.log('show data', final_ids);` always returns me `undefined`.

I tried other methods too to achieve the same, but every time it gave undefine.

Please help to sort this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InterviewWorflowDao.findAll({}, function (err, docs) { 
   return new Promise( (res, rej) => {

     if (err) rej(err)

     res(docs)
  })
});
```

in your Higher-order-function

```
const findAll = (query, cb) => {

    model.find(query, null, cb)
    .then( idDocs => console.log(idDocs))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));

}
```

**other option:**

```
async function runQuery(){
  let modelIds = await findAll({},  (err, docs) => { 
          return docs
   });

   console.log(modelIds)

}

runQuery()
```

HOF:

```
const findAll = (query, cb) => {
    return new Promise( (res, rej) => {

        res(model.find(query, '_id', cb))

    })
}
```

Comment: Yes the model in HOF is the model defined for a particualr schema from database

Comment: In this function, const findAll = (query, cb) => {

    model.find(query, null, cb);

}, I need result in findAll, so that it can be used somewhere else. But its gives undefined even when the result in available inside the callback function

Comment: I change my answer, cheeckit

Comment: I changed my answer again jaja cheeck it please

Comment: Can you please move it to a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214340/discussion-between-bubble-cord-and-max).

Answer (score 1):

The query function is asynchronous, so the console.log function and everything else what uses the result should be inside the callback:

```
InterviewWorflowDao.findAll({}, (err, res) => {
  const user_ids = res.map(r => r.clientId);
  console.log('show data', user_ids);
  return user_ids;            
})
```

Comment: I tried the first approach. And Console.log('final ids', final_ids) is still undefined

Comment: Can you look at my HOF? If I can use async-await inside that?

Comment: The async-await approach, const findAll is not readable by .findAll(). I have also removed return statements but its not readable as await IntervalWorkflowDao.findAll();